# Laravel - how to copy collection to a new variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-collection

I wanted to change my collection set to a new variable, but it changed the original.

I thought this was a JavaScript issue and PHP was referring to value.

How do I set my collection to a new variable, which I can alter without changing the original collection.

```
$pets = Pet::all();
$tmp = $pets;
$tmp->pop();
$pets->dd(); // This value also has it's last item removed.
```

I'm using this workaround for now:

```
$tmp = $pets->map(function (item) {
    return $item;
});
$tmp->pop();
$pets->dd(); // This value is now unchanged.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `clone`

```
$pets = Pet::all();
$tmp =clone $pets;
$tmp->pop();
$pets->dd();
```

If you like to use collection then add method to collection using macro in `AppServiceProvider` boot method

```
public function boot()
{
      
   Collection::macro('clone', function() {
       return clone $this;
    });

}
```

then you can do the following

```
$pets = Pet::all();
$tmp =$pets->clone();
$tmp->pop();
$pets->dd();
```